# Create kubernetes nginx ingress without GCP load-balancer

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress

So I'm using Kubernetes for a side project and it's great. It's cheaper to run for a small project like the one I'm on (a small cluster of 3-5 instances gives me basically everything I need for ~$30/month on GCP).

The only area where I'm struggling is in trying to use the kubernetes Ingress resource to map into cluster and fan out to my microservices (they're small Go or Node backends). I have the configuration setup for the ingress to map to different services and there's no problem there.

I understand that you can really easily have GCP spin up a LoadBalancer when you create an ingress resource. This is fine, but it also represents another $20-ish/month that adds to the cost of the project. Once/if this thing gets some traction, that could be ignored, but for now and also for the sake of understanding Kubernetes better, I want to the do the following:

- get a static IP from GCP,
- use it w/ an ingress resource
- host the load-balancer in the same cluster (using the nginx load balancer)
- avoid paying for the external load balancer

Is there any way this can even be done using Kubernetes and ingress resources?

Thanks!

Comment: Happy to post my existing configs if needed — just curious first if this is even something you can do :)

Comment: Not to mention many K8s tools leave inactive Load Balancers behind, for me it went up to $30 a month just for useless Load Balancers.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes this is possible. Deploy your ingress controller, and deploy it with a NodePort service. Example:

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx-ingress-controller
  namespace: kube-system
  labels:
    k8s-app: nginx-ingress-controller
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 80
    nodePort: 32080
    protocol: TCP
    name: http
  - port: 443
    targetPort: 443
    nodePort: 32443
    protocol: TCP
    name: https
  selector:
    k8s-app: nginx-ingress-controller
```

Now, create an ingress with a DNS entry:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-ingress
spec:
  rules:
  - host: myapp.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: my-app-service #obviously point this to a valid service + port
          servicePort: 80
```

Now, assuming your static IP is attached to any kubernetes node running kube-proxy, have DNS updated to point to the static IP, and you should be able to visit `myapp.example.com:32080` and the ingress will map you back to your app.

A few additional things:

If you want to use a lower port than 32080, then bear in mind if you're using CNI networking, [you'll have trouble with hostport](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/23920). It's recommend to have a load balancer listening on port 80, I guess you could just have nginx set up to do proxy pass, but it becomes difficult. This is why a load balancer with your cloud provider is recommended :)

Comment: For those who are using the [nginx-ingress](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/nginx-ingress) helm chart, this is easily done by adding the `--set controller.service.type=NodePort` flag during installation or upgrade of the helm chart. *HOWEVER*, exposing node ports is not trivial on [VPC-native clusters](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/alias-ips), so I have not yet been able to get this approach to work for me.

Comment: @Cameron Hudson Actually, exposing the node port was not bad. See my answer in this thread. However, I haven't found away to use node ports 80 or 443 on GCP, because the `service-node-port-range` option is not accessible to us on GCP. (For what I'm talking about, see here: http://www.thinkcode.se/blog/2019/02/20/kubernetes-service-node-port-range).

Answer (score 4):

**TLDR: If you want to serve your website/webservice on ports below 3000, then no, it's not possible.** If someone finds a way to do it, I'd be eager to know how.

The two main approaches I used while trying to serve on a port below 3000 included:

- Installing the `nginx-ingress` controller service to be of type `NodePort`, listening on ports 80 and 443. However, this results in the following error:

  ```
  Error: UPGRADE FAILED: Service "nginx-ingress-controller" is invalid:
  spec.ports[0].nodePort: Invalid value: 80: provided port is not in the
  valid range. The range of valid ports is 30000-32767
  ```

  The way to work around this error is to change the `--service-node-port-range` flag used when starting `kube-apiserver`. However, this configuration cannot be accessed on GCP. If you'd like to try for yourself, you can check out the instructions here: [Kubernetes service node port range](http://www.thinkcode.se/blog/2019/02/20/kubernetes-service-node-port-range)
- Following the steps in the thread [Expose port 80 and 443 on Google Container Engine without load balancer](https://serverfault.com/questions/801189/expose-port-80-and-443-on-google-container-engine-without-load-balancer). This relies on using an `externalIP` attribute attached to a `service` of `type: ClusterIP`. At first glance, this would seem to be an ideal solution. However, there is a bug in the way that the `externalIP` attribute works. It does not accept an external, static IP, but rather an internal, ephemeral IP. If you hardcode an internal, ephemeral IP in the `externalIP` field, and then attach an external, static IP to one of the nodes in your cluster through the GCP Console, *requests are successfully routed*. However, this is not a viable solution because you've now hardcoded an ephemeral IP in your `service` definition, so your website will inevitably go offline as the nodes' internal IPs change.

If you are okay with serving on ports above 3000, see my instructions below.

---

### How to remove the LoadBalancer (only allows serving on ports > 3000)

I've tried removing my LoadBalancer, and this is the best solution I could come up with. It has the following flaws:

- The ports used to access the webpage are not the usual 80 and 443 because exposing these ports from a node is not trivial. I'll update later if I figure it out.

And the following benefits:

- There's no LoadBalancer.
- The IP of the website/webservice is static.
- It's relies on the popular `nginx-ingress` helm chart.
- It uses an `ingress`, allowing complete control over how requests are routed to your `services` based on the paths of the requests.

#### 1. Install the ingress service and controller

Assuming you already have Helm installed (if you don't follow the steps here: [Installing Helm on GKE](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/nginx-ingress-gke)), create an `nginx-ingress` with a `type` of `NodePort`.

```
helm install \
  --name nginx-ingress \
  stable/nginx-ingress \
  --set rbac.create=true \
  --set controller.publishService.enabled=true \
  --set controller.service.type=NodePort \
  --set controller.service.nodePorts.http=30080 \
  --set controller.service.nodePorts.https=30443
```

#### 2. Create the ingress resource

Create the ingress definition for your routing.

```
# my-ingress-resource.yaml

apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: reverse-proxy
  namespace: production # Namespace must be the same as that of target services below.
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false" # Set to true once SSL is set up.
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /api
        backend:
          serviceName: backend
          servicePort: 3000
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: frontend
          servicePort: 80
```

Then install it with

```
kubectl apply -f my-ingress-resource.yaml
```

#### 3. Create a firewall rule

Find the tag of your cluster.

```
gcloud compute instances list
```

If your cluster instances have names like

```
gke-cluster-1-pool-1-fee097a3-n6c8
gke-cluster-1-pool-1-fee097a3-zssz
```

Then your cluster tag is `gke-cluster-1-pool-1-fee097a3`.

Go to [the GCP firewall page](https://console.cloud.google.com/networking/firewalls). *Verify that you have the right project selected in the navbar.*

Click "Create Firewall Rule". Give the rule a decent name. You can leave most of the settings as defaults, but past your cluster tag under "Target tags". Set the Source IP Ranges to `0.0.0.0/0`. Under Protocols and Ports, **change "Allow all" to "Specified protocols and ports".** Check the TCP box, and put `30080, 30443` in the input field. Click "Create".

#### 4. Create a static IP

Go to https://console.cloud.google.com/networking/addresses/ and click "Reserve Static Address". Give it a descriptive name, and select the correct region. After selecting the correct region, you should be able to click the "Attached to" dropdown and select one of your Kubernetes nodes. Click "Reserve".

#### 5. Test the configuration

After reserving the static IP, find out which static IP was granted by looking at the [External IP Address list](https://console.cloud.google.com/networking/addresses/).

Copy it into your browser, then tack on a port (`<your-ip>:30080` for HTTP or `https://<your-ip>:30443` for HTTPS). You should see your webpage.

Comment: Nginx ingress without lb has one more flaw that the static ip is attached to a node which can go down.

Comment: And also what about using `hostport` instead of `nodeport` for using ports below 3000 ? see https://stackoverflow.com/a/54297777/5457916

Answer (score 0):

You can also make an nginx-ingress chart, have it pull an ephemeral IP and then upgrade it to static. This would leave you with a L7 single zone load balancer.

This guide goes through it. You can ignore the TLS stuff if you use kube-lego, which works just as well with nginx-ingress

https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/tree/master/docs/examples/static-ip

Answer (score 0):

The [original source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54119399/expose-port-80-on-digital-oceans-managed-kubernetes-without-a-load-balancer), but it contains Digital Ocean details that I never used. It honestly saved my life, and **it is possible** to use ports under 3000, but I honestly am not sure how it works.

My setup is using the this [Nginx ingress controller.](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx) Install it using helm, and provide it a configuration file:

```
$ helm install my-nginx ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx -f config.yaml
```

The configuration file should contain:

```
controller:
  kind: DaemonSet
  hostNetwork: true
  dnsPolicy: ClusterFirstWithHostNet
  daemonset:
    useHostPort: true
  service:
    type: ClusterIP
rbac:
  create: true
```

You can find the default values [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/master/charts/ingress-nginx/values.yaml), but I have no idea how to make sense out of that config.

After that you can create your ingress yaml:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: web-app
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: "100m"
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: "letsencrypt"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-alias: "example.com"
  labels:
    app: web-app
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
      - example.com
      secretName: prod-certs
  rules:
    - host: example.com
      http: 
        paths:
        - backend:
            serviceName: myservice
            servicePort: 443
```

This is mine, it could be that for you it won't work, but try it!

The service ingress rule it points to is `NodePort` type:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: myservice
  labels:
    app: myservice
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - port: 443
    targetPort: 80
```

But I believe `ClusterIP` works as well.

Outside of that, one of the VMs has a public static IP, and we use that IP for our domain name.

So the process I believe is. The domain name translates to that static IP. Then the traffic hits the Ingress controller, I have no idea how this works, but there your traffic gets matched to some rule, and is redirected to the service. The ports are defined in the Ingress, so you can also use under 3000 ports, but I have no idea how this "solution" works performance-wise, and I also have no idea how can Ingress controller accept traffic if it is not exposed.

Setting up Ingress was possibly one of the worst experiences I had, and I actually went with this chaos approach because working with `LoadBalancer` service types was even worse. Best of luck!