# Is there a way to not use GKE's standard load balancer?

Tags: kubernetes, google-compute-engine, traefik

I'm trying to use Kubernetes to make configurations and deployments explicitly defined and I also like Kubernetes' pod scheduling mechanisms. There are (for now) just 2 apps running on 2 replicas on 3 nodes. But Google's Kubernetes Engine's load balancer is extremely expensive for a small app like ours (at least for the moment) at the same time I'm not willing to change to a single instance hosting solution on a container or deploying the app on Docker swarm etc.

Using node's IP seemed like a hack and I thought that it might expose some security issues inside the cluster. Therefore I configured a Træfik ingress and an ingress controller to overcome Google's expensive flat rate for load balancing but turns out an outward facing ingress spins up a standart load balancer or I'm missing something.

I hope I'm missing something since at this rates ($16 a month) I cannot rationalize using kubernetes from start up for this app.

Is there a way to use GKE without using Google's load balancer?

Comment: You can see if this helps you: https://serverfault.com/questions/863569/kubernetes-can-i-avoid-using-the-gce-load-balancer-to-reduce-cost/869453#869453

Answer (score 7):

An `Ingress` is just a set of rules that tell the cluster how to route to your services, and a `Service` is another set of rules to reach and load-balance across a set of pods, based on the selector. A service can use 3 different routing types:

- `ClusterIP` - this gives the service an IP that's only available inside the cluster which routes to the pods.
- `NodePort` - this creates a ClusterIP, and then creates an externally reachable port on every single node in the cluster. Traffic to those ports routes to the internal service IP and then to the pods.
- `LoadBalancer` - this creates a ClusterIP, then a NodePort, and then provisions a load balancer from a provider (if available like on GKE). Traffic hits the load balancer, then a port on one of the nodes, then the internal IP, then finally a pod.

These different types of services are not mutually exclusive but actually build on each other, and it explains why anything public must be using a NodePort. Think about it - how else would traffic reach your cluster? A cloud load balancer just directs requests to your nodes and points to one of the NodePort ports. If you don't want a GKE load balancer then you can already skip it and access those ports directly.

The downside is that the ports are limited between 30000-32767. If you need standard HTTP port 80/443 then you can't accomplish this with a `Service` and instead must specify the port directly in your `Deployment`. Use the `hostPort` setting to bind the containers directly to port 80 on the node:

```
containers:
  - name: yourapp
    image: yourimage
    ports:
      - name: http
        containerPort: 80
        hostPort: 80 ### this will bind to port 80 on the actual node
```

This might work for you and routes traffic directly to the container without any load-balancing, but if a node has problems or the app stops running on a node then it will be unavailable.

If you still want load-balancing then you can run a `DaemonSet` (so that it's available on every node) with Nginx (or any other proxy) exposed via `hostPort` and then that will route to your internal services. An easy way to run this is with the standard `nginx-ingress` package, but skip creating the LoadBalancer service for it and use the `hostPort` setting. The Helm chart can be configured for this:

https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/nginx-ingress

Comment: Thanks Mani for the detailed info, also I believe that to use hostPort you need to enable hostNetwork: true under spec section where containers are defined.

Answer (score 5):

One option is to completely disable this feature on your GKE cluster. When creating the cluster (on console.cloud.google.com) under **Add-ons** disable **HTTP load balancing**. If you are using `gcloud` you can use `gcloud beta container clusters create ... --disable-addons=HttpLoadBalancing`.

Alternatively, you can also inhibit the GCP Load Balancer by adding an **annotation to your Ingress resources**, `kubernetes.io/ingress.class=somerandomstring`.

**For newly created ingresses**, you can put this in the yaml document:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: somerandomstring
...
```

If you want to do that for **all of your Ingresses** you can use this example snippet (be careful!):

```
kubectl get ingress --all-namespaces \
  -o jsonpath='{range .items[*]}{"kubectl annotate ingress -n "}{.metadata.namespace}{" "}{.metadata.name}{" kubernetes.io/ingress.class=somerandomstring\n"}{end}' \
  | sh -x
```

Now using Ingresses is pretty useful with Kubernetes, so I suggest you check out the [nginx ingress controller](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/master/README.md) and after deployment, annotate your Ingresses accordingly.

Comment: Can I bind the ingress with a static ip?

Comment: This depends on the ingress controller being used. For GCP Load Balancer, yes.

Comment: I guess it was not clear on the question that by saying GKE's standard load balancer I meant GCP load balancer. I'm trying to somehow remove GCP Load balancer from the system and also bind to a static ip.

Answer (score 3):

If you specify the Ingress class as an annotation on the Ingress object

```
kubernetes.io/ingress.class: traefik
```

Traefik will pick it up while the Google Load Balancer will ignore it. There is also [a bit of Traefik documentation on this part](https://docs.traefik.io/user-guide/kubernetes/#between-trfik-and-other-ingress-controller-implementations).

Comment: Does this completely skip the creation of the Load Balancing rule? Essentially OP doesn't want to be charged for Cloud Load Balancing

Comment: Yes, it should skip the entire Google LB creation process, including the rules. Essentially, how it's implemented is that there's a Google LB controller (short, glbc) running in GKE clusters that watches for Ingresses which have the right `ingress.class` annotation value. For Ingresses that do not satisfy this condition, glbc will skip them entirely and not reach out to the GCP API at all.

Answer (score 0):

You could deploy the nginx ingress controller using `NodePort` mode (e.g. if using the [helm chart](https://github.com/kubernetes/charts/tree/master/stable/nginx-ingress) set `controller.service.type` to `NodePort`) and then load-balance amongst your instances using DNS. Just make sure you have static IPs for the nodes or you could even create a `DaemonSet` that somehow updates your DNS with each node's IP.

Traefik seems to support a similar configuration (e.g. through `serviceType` in its [helm chart](https://github.com/kubernetes/charts/tree/master/stable/traefik)).

Comment: NodePort will give me a port which is greater than 3000 I need to bind port 80 on that static ip.

Comment: Ah ok, you can try hostPort then - in the nginx helm chart set controller.daemonset.useHostPort